# Rewrite MarkLogic xml document dynamically based on strings in XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I need an XQuery function that is capable of rewriting a document, specifically returning a subset of child nodes, based on an array of strings specifying names of nodes to retrieve. If should satisfy a definition like the below and needs to work with any arbitrary document.

```
local:apply-node-includes($document, $includedNodeNames as xs:string*)
```

Given I had some xml doc

```
let $doc := 
  <foo a="b">
    <bar>hello</bar>
    <baz>1</baz>
    <bang>
      <text>world</text>
    </bang>
  </foo>')
```

Then the function should transform the document such that only child nodes with a name specified in $includedNodes are returned.

Example `local:apply-node-includes($doc, 'baz')` would return

```
<foo a="b">
  <baz>1</baz>
</foo>
```

Example `local:apply-node-includes($doc, ('bar','bang')))` would return

```
<foo a="b">
  <bar>hello</bar>
  <bang>
    <text>world</text>
  </bang>
</foo>
```

I experimented iterating over the nodes, and/or using some form of recursive typeswitch but have so far been unable to get it right. It would be really cool if it worked fully recursively so 'bang.text' would include only grandchildren text nodes and not any siblings of them but maybe that is asking too much!

Comment: Consider having your function take a sequence of xs:QNames rather than strings. What you have works because your XML uses the default namespace, but in the presence of namespaces, you'd have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but appears to meet your requirements.  The function here recreates the root element of the passed document and then includes any immediate child elements (and all of their attributes and children) having an element name matching any of the strings in the passed list.

```
declare function local:apply-node-includes( $doc as item(), $includedNodeNames as xs:string*) as item()
{
   (: Recreate the root element :)
   element {name($doc)} 
   { (: Replicate root element's attributes :)
     (for    $attribute in $doc/@* return $attribute),
     (: Replicate root element's immediate children having any of given names :)
     (for    $element in $doc/* where name($element) = $includedNodeNames 
      return $element)
   }
};

let $doc := 
  <foo a="b">
    <bar>hello</bar>
    <baz>1</baz>
    <bang>
      <text>world</text>
    </bang>
  </foo>
return local:apply-node-includes($doc, ('bar','bang'))
```

Output:

```
<foo a="b"><bar>hello</bar><bang><text>world</text></bang></foo>
```

Comment: I have corrected those typos, and thanks for the answer. I have accepted yours but posted a refined verion for others to follow.

Answer (score 1):

@DavidDeneberg gave a pretty good answer, but I managed to simplify it further using some xpath so posting for others.

```
declare function local:apply-node-includes($doc as element(), $includedNodeNames as xs:string*) as element()?
{
  element {node-name($doc) }
  {
    $doc/@*,
    $doc/*[name(.)=$include-names]
  }
};
```

Also this book is very useful on the topic
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Filtering_Nodes and demonstrates the kind of recursive Identity Transform you would need to be able to handle the grandchildren part of the question.